# servidor gratis para teste(php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, servidor

Talvez esse não seja o foco da comunidade, mas alguém sabe de um servidor grátis para testar php e mysql?

Comment: Hostinger, Xiro. Hospedagem gratuita, mas não funciona o engine InnoDB, portanto sem chaves estrangeiras, mas é excelente, uso há cerca de um ano já.

Comment: "engine InnoDB, portanto sem chaves estrangeiras" não posso colocar um bd grande com relação de tabela???

Comment: De graça não, só pagando. Talvez exista outro, mas ainda não encontrei no google, se souber de outro que aceite me avise, hehe. Boa sorte!

Comment: Obriago. tenho que colocar um bd "grande". kkkk.. aviso sim.